# Bootstrap won't work properly

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, view

[image: this is my code so far]
[image]

I've tried this exact code on my other computer and once run it is shown differently. Could you correctly show me how I should insert the references? Also how could I override the style of the default bootstrap?
I think that's all the info you need, but if you need anything else just ask.

Comment: Provide your script

Comment: You should include Jquery before you include bootstrap

Comment: Are your computers both windows or it is a window and a mac? Because from reading about the "~" in your path to bootstrap, it seems as though macs don't have the "~" as something that should be included in the path. 

Actually, from my understanding, only UNIX based machines use it - therefore macs don't know what it means.

Comment: if your html file is under wwwroot you can remove ~/ symbols if not, you can use ../ symbols instead ~/

Comment: @jobairahmed i dont know which script you mean,

Comment: @JohnF. so i just put the Jquery ref before the bootstrap?

Comment: @RyanGreen one computer is windows the other mac but im using parallel desktops on it hence its also windows.

Comment: @AliAkyıldırım my html file is not under wwwroot, its under my views

Comment: So, you can use ../ symbols instead ~/ as I said above

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you html file is inside `wwwroot` folder, so:

```
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
    ...
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: My html file is in my Views folder, it isnt inside wwwroot folder.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't see any Views folder in your ss. Just set the correct path of the bootstrap file in your html file.

Comment: yeah, the thing is it works fine on one computer and on the other(exact same code) the links are pretty much default links

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Remove the `~`.

I believe that the `~` is a Windows only thing used for finding the path. If it's your mac where Bootstrap is not working, then I'm 98% sure that was the issue. `~` isn't used in the mac environment for paths like it is on Windows.

You will also need to do that for your other paths being found this way.

Comment: They are both windows but one of them is running on parallel desktop, exact same code but when i run it the links are not decorated

Answer (score 0):

Going in and changing the bootstrap CSS can get a little complicated so I usually create a new CSS file with my edits.  Since CSS is cascading stylesheets, I make sure that my CSS file is the last stylesheet in the head section so it overrides the stylesheets above it.

The location of your CSS file in reference to your HTML file will determine what the file path looks like in your reference.  If your HTML file is in the root directory, the reference/paths mentioned in the other answers should work.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above:

```
<link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Remove `~`.

If you want to overwrite CSS place the `default.css` or your own css after the one you want to overwrite for example:

```
<!-- Bootstrap and Custom CSS Style Sheets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css">
```